# How to offline install STS from the provided archived update site?

Tags: offline, spring-tool-suite

Spring-Boot team nicely provides [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xETLi.png),
all what is required to update eclipse with STS tools.

Trying to install STS on my offline Redhat7 eclipse installation, 
via help/install new software/add/work-with:
jar:file:/pathto/springsource-tool-suite-3.8.4.RELEASE-e4.6.3-updatesite.zip!/

I can freely select the softwares available in the archive but 
the first step: "Calculating requirements dependency"
never finish. [image: requireent dependencies calculation never finish]

Would anyone have any clue of how to install springsource-tool-suite-3.8.4.RELEASE-e4.6.3-updatesite.zip content on an offline redhat7 eclipse installation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to disable Eclipse Software Sites.

as detailed [here](https://www.dvteclipse.com/documentation/e/How_do_I_disable_Eclipse_Software_Sites.3F.html).